# NavigationView Menu not respond on Click Listener

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout, navigationview

In my android application i have created NavigationView, however i don't know why i can't select the menu i have made.

Here is the `activity_main.xml` with `DrawerLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_containers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_app_bar"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu">



</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and here is my `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

    initNavigationView();

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_containers) != null){

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            return;
        }

        displayView(R.id.nav_profile);

    }

}

private void initNavigationView() {

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            drawerView.bringToFront();
            drawerView.requestLayout();
        }
    };


    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    FirebaseFirestore user_firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
    headerImage = (CircleImageView)  headerView.findViewById(R.id.headerImage);
    headerNama = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.headerNama);
    headerNim = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.headerNim);

    String uid = mAuth.getUid();

    user_firestore.collection("Users").document(uid).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                if(task.getResult().exists()){

                    String nama = task.getResult().getString("nama");
                    String nim = task.getResult().getString("nim");
                    String image = task.getResult().getString("image");

                    headerNama.setText(nama);
                    headerNim.setText(nim);

                    RequestOptions placeholderRequest = new RequestOptions();
                    placeholderRequest.placeholder(R.drawable.email_photo);

                    Uri download_image = Uri.parse(image);
                    Glide.with(headerView).setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest).load(download_image).into(headerImage);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data tidak ditemukan!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            } else {

                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "(Firestore Error) : " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null){

        sendToLogin();

    }
}

private void sendToLogin() {

    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
    finish();

}

public void setToolbarTitle(String title){

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

}

private void signOut() {

    mAuth.signOut();
    Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(logoutIntent);
    finish();

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else {

        if(!viewAtHome){ //if tampilan bukan pada Home View

            displayView(R.id.nav_home);

        } else {

            moveTaskToBack(true);

        }

    }
}

public void displayView(int viewId){

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(viewId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new MainFragment();
            viewAtHome = true;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_profile:
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            viewAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_out:
            signOut();
            break;
    }

    if(fragment != null){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_containers, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
```

i have searching how to solve the problem but still can't to fix this.
thanks for advice, and sorry my grammar is to bad.

Comment: You forgot to call `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks sir it's work